# pythonic way to sort a list of lists by the last item of the inner list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list like this

```
[[x,y,1],[w,u,4],[m,n,3] ... [p,q,5]]
```

I need to sort the outer list by the third (last) element of the inner list, the desired result would be:

```
[[x,y,1],[m,n,3],[w,u,4] ... [p,q,5]]
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

or

```
my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(-1))
```

The second option is slightly faster.

Comment: Just for completeness, consider also `sorted(my_list, key=same_as_before)`