# custom sort a list of list of numbers in ascending order

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pythonic way to sort a list of lists by the last item of the inner list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020408/pythonic-way-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-the-last-item-of-the-inner-list)

I have a list of list of numbers that looks like this:

```
rows = [[100,1.17902838317,4.30281847041,4.30598958666,4.31258472331,10.9269044537,1.17902838317]
[110,1.3978813526,1.39847341928,1.39950407438,1.4016475818,5.17927032236,1.3978813526]
[120,2.95045527752,2.95170493026,2.95388029498,2.95840451497,7.49578397746,2.95045527752]
[30,3.14439495993,3.145726755,3.14714447001,3.15196469714,7.9862122826,3.14439495993]
[40,3.35171204965,3.62204712952,3.62308999951,3.62767337976,8.49979359433,3.62120669609]
[50,2.63010055396,2.66403524005,2.66637361988,2.67045748911,6.76620535091,2.63010055396]
[60,3.09088634745,3.09219547918,3.09447438343,3.09921394005,9.71470661115,3.09088634745]
[70,1.42116996887,1.42199838776,1.42411423836,2.27074446576,3.60990507963,2.26985641041]
[80,1.7602934006,1.76103896537,1.76233682613,1.76503605518,4.4721162759,1.7602934006]
[90,1.27784662871,1.2783878552,1.27933000894,1.28128945544,3.24643534107,1.27784662871]
]
```

I want to write a sort func that will return the original list sorted using the integer in the first column, so the sorted list would look like this:

```
30,3.14439495993,3.145726755,3.14714447001,3.15196469714,7.9862122826,3.14439495993
40,3.35171204965,3.62204712952,3.62308999951,3.62767337976,8.49979359433,3.62120669609
50,2.63010055396,2.66403524005,2.66637361988,2.67045748911,6.76620535091,2.63010055396
60,3.09088634745,3.09219547918,3.09447438343,3.09921394005,9.71470661115,3.09088634745
70,1.42116996887,1.42199838776,1.42411423836,2.27074446576,3.60990507963,2.26985641041
80,1.7602934006,1.76103896537,1.76233682613,1.76503605518,4.4721162759,1.7602934006
90,1.27784662871,1.2783878552,1.27933000894,1.28128945544,3.24643534107,1.27784662871
100,1.17902838317,4.30281847041,4.30598958666,4.31258472331,10.9269044537,1.17902838317
110,1.3978813526,1.39847341928,1.39950407438,1.4016475818,5.17927032236,1.3978813526
120,2.95045527752,2.95170493026,2.95388029498,2.95840451497,7.49578397746,2.95045527752
```

How can I write such a custom sort function?

Attempt so far:

```
def mysort_func(row):
    # get the integer of row[1]
    # do something with it (simply return it?)
    pass


new_list = sorted(rows, key=mysort_func)
```

Comment: I'm confused.  The title of this question mentions a "list of strings" and you say that the "values are strings", but your example doesn't contain any strings and you accepted an answer which will only work if they're not strings.  Something needs to be edited.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted(rows, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

or

```
import operator
sorted(rows, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

simply could use sort function:

```
rows.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(rows, key=itemgetter(0)))
```